# Pinning cloth to moving model

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly pin cloth to a moving object. The cloth is acting as a mane for a horse and therefore needs to be pinned in multiple places. I've looked at several tutorials but can't really 'transfer' the technique used to get the result I want. How can I pin cloth to multiple points on a moving model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Select the cloth. Enter Weight paint mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, assign weights of 1 to the vertices you want to pin (paint with brush these vertices red)
- In cloth physics settings, check 'pinning' and select the vertex group
- Then enter Object mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>. Make sure to select the cloth first and then the object you want to pin on.
- Parent the cloth to the object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and select 'Set parent to object'

Comment: This solution should work just as well as the hook modifier (and is simpler), as long as all vertices are to be pinned as a unit to a single item.  If you want parts pinned to one bone and other parts to another bone, the hook modifier might become necessary.

Comment: Basically pin part of the cloth and then parent the cloth object so the pin follows the parent around?

Answer (score 6):

1. Pin a vertex group in your cloth sim settings
2. Hook those pin vertices to something.  For my test I used <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd> to hook them to a new empty. You will probably hook them to a bone or something.
3. Go into the modifier panel and move the Hook-Empty modifier **above** the cloth modifier in the stack.

After doing that, I was able to drag the cloth around by animating the empty.

Comment: This method is definitely not working for me. The hook is being completely ignored by the simulation no matter what I try.

I have tried assigning the vertex's to a group and choosing that as a group in the hook modified, and I have tried the hook modifier in both positions above and below the cloth modifier. It is absolutely ignoring the hook.

Stumped.