# How to position a poncho with cloth physics

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm working on a character who is wearing a poncho:

[image]

The poncho has cloth physics, and the character is a collision object. To get the model in that screenshot, I started with a flat subdivided plane with a head hole cut out, I positioned it around his neck, and the physics drop it around his body.

I'm trying to figure out if I can "pose" the poncho differently. I'd like to have it like this:

[image]

Is there a good way to achieve this pose?

Comment: If you want to animate between both states through simulation, it might be difficult in Blender, as cloth physics are not that refined - mainly cloth collision and self-collision will be problem. With bones and shapekeys you can imho do a good result. If there is no need for transition I would sculpt the clothes in their final form and add some bones or simulation for wind effects and such.

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71727/919

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out this answer from Faceb Faceb. My first thought is to grab a few vertices on your poncho, and assign them to a group. In your cloth physics settings, check the "pinning" option. You should be able to use that same vertex group to parent to the cloth to the shoulder of your character. The tricky part is, you'll have to 'pose' the cloth in edit mode all stretched out, and when you apply physics, the cloth should fall into place, and the pinned verts should stick to your object. Check out more here:

[Pinning cloth to moving model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32972/pinning-cloth-to-moving-model)